# .NET Standard not installed on Linux?

Tags: linux, mono, .net-standard

I use Mono + MonoDevelop on Linux, and I've recently heard about something called *.NET Standard*. Since the Mono v4.8.0 changelog says that they're adding support for *.NET Standard* 2.0 (we're now on v5.14 now), I assumed I didn't need to do anything.

When I went to test it out today, I discovered that not only can I not see *.NET Standard 2.0* in the list of versions I can use for a *.NET Standard 2.0* class library (only up to v1.6 - what happened to *Console Apps*?), but *MonoDevelop* claims that I don't have *.NET Standard 1.6* installed.

That's ridiculous though - *.NET Standard* is a standard specification, right? Isn't this like asking me to "Install HTML5"?

Can anyone help me clear up my confusion please?

**System Details:**

- `uname -a`: `Linux Riikaan 4.15.0-34-generic #37-Ubuntu SMP Mon Aug 27 15:21:48 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`
- Distribution: Ubuntu Desktop 18.04
- Mono version: `5.14.0.177`
- MonoDevelop version: `7.5 (build 1255)`
- I installed `mono` and `monodevelop` via the official `apt` repository available [here](https://www.mono-project.com/download/stable/).

**Screenshots:**

[image]

[image]

Comment: what version of MonoDevelop? what version of Mono (and how did you install it)? what version of Linux?

Comment: Ah, good questions @knocte. I've updated my question with additional details.

Comment: this sentence is confusing: `I discovered that not only can I not need .NET Standard 2.0 in the list of versions I can use for a .NET Standard 2.0 class library`, better to show a screenshot of what you're seeing

Comment: Corrected - that `need` should be a `see`. Here's the list when I create  a new solution, @knocte: https://i.imgur.com/QZZfHto.png

Comment: before installing the repositories in https://www.mono-project.com/download/stable/ , did you uninstall previous mono packages?

Comment: I recommend adding another screenshot about the message that MonoDevelop says

Comment: @knocte Yes, I did. Good idea about the screenshots - I've added them to the question.

Comment: ok with all these info and screenshots IMO you already have a good case to submitting 2 bug reports in https://github.com/mono/monodevelop/ , one for the missing 2.0 and the other one for the confusing *.netstandard not installed* message; because in fact if you create a .NET Standard 2.0 C# lib with Visual Studio for Mac and take it to Linux, msbuild can build it, therefore MonoDevelop should build it too

Comment: Ah, ok! Thanks for the info there, @knocte. I've opened an issue here: https://github.com/mono/monodevelop/issues/6146

Comment: A project targeting a certain .NET Standard version requires a profile, so that the C# compiler can know which APIs are available. Like @knocte pointed out, that might indicate bugs in MonoDevelop, as your machine should have the bits. I usually install `mono-complete` via apt on development machine, which has more bits.

Comment: @LexLi I see. I do believe that I have `mono-complete` installed though :-/